# Select a meta_key if another meta_key is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm using

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_value  
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1' 
AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND meta_value != ''
```

to return all the `meta_key`'s with the name `_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1` which are not empty.

But what I need to do in a separate query is to return all the `post_id`'s of rows that have `meta_value` of the meta_key `_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1` which is not empty. But this returns nothing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT meta_key 'post_id'  
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE '_wcj_custom_product_tabs_content_local_1' 
AND meta_value IS NOT NULL
AND meta_value != ''
```

[image]

Comment: Your two queries look exactly the same except for the column alias.

Comment: So how do I change the column alias?

Comment: `meta_key, post_id` instead of `meta_key 'post_id'`

Comment: @Shadow Thanks! That works; you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Shadow, add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.